# Android Jetpack Compose: Can't find OutlinedTextField in Empty Compose Activity (Material3)

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

When I create new project and select "Empty Compose Activity (Material3)",
I can't use OutlinedTextField.

[image: OutlinedTextField not shown]

When I create new project and select "Empty Compose Activity"
it's Ok
[image: OutlinedTextField shown]

Why there is a different and how can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe the **OutlinedTextField** is not a part of the Material3 package. Check the package of the **OutlinedTextField**. Then check if your project has this dependency. If not, add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` upgrade the Material3 dependency to the [latest](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3) as below.

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.1'
```

This shows `OutlinedTextField` in the project.

You must also add the `@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)` to your function as below.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
)
```